# How do I "uneject" an iPad from iTunes?

Tags: ios, ipad, itunes

I have an iPad and I want to sync it via wifi. That works fine. Sometimes I mistakenly eject the iPad from iTunes and then it does not synchronize anymore ("searching for my MacBook"). Can I instruct iTunes to search for my iPad again? To undo the eject? I use the newest OS on my MacBook and iPad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested with my iPhone, and I can get it to reappear in the **Devices** list simply by quitting iTunes and reopening it (waking up your iPad may help iTunes find it faster). If that doesn't work, simply plug it in via USB and it should stay in.

Comment: After I have rebooted my MacBook, it worked as you described. Before that, I have tried it several times and even with plugging it in and out, the iPad disappeared again. iTunes is a monster, right? :)

Comment: Strange that you needed a reboot, but glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

You can initiate a sync directly from the iPad, the device will then appear in iTunes again as well.